# AJAX и обновление страницы

Tags: ajax

Ситуация такая:
Клиент заходит на сайт, переходит в корзину.
Затем открывает вторую вкладку и начинает добавлять туда товары.
Потом открывает первую вкладку, обновляет страницу, что бы посмотреть, что он там навыбирал, и...
...сайт на AJAX (не знаю можно ли так выразиться, поправьте).

Клиент оказывается на главной страницы.
Он не знает что такое AJAX, у него паника - где корзина, почему я снова должен жать на корзину?

Итого:
Нужно что бы после обновления страницы, сайт брал последний загруженный url и по нему обновлял контент.

На сайте есть history, back<->forward работает с ajax.
Но как перезагрузку прикрутить не ума.
Даже что гуглить не знаю.

Подскажите возможно ли такое решить?

Comment: А в чем загвоздка то? При заходе на страницу проверяется линк, по нему открывается что надо. Зашел куда-то -> `History.pushState()`, вышел -> `History.back()`

Comment: По ctrl+F5 что делать? Как отловить?

Comment: через `history.pushState()` вы изменяете url, при заходе на страницу/обновлении - парсится урл и определяется что отображать.